# Access memory and changing the value of some variables

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I am trying to create a communication between one server and many clients.The server starts and waits for a client to connect.I manage to have many sockets simultaneously open via select.When I pass some information from client to server and after to another client, a variable that is stored, for example, the client's IP (in char* type) changes with the variable I just read

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
address.sin_family = AF_INET;

address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(clientIP);
address.sin_port = htons(clientport);


int addrlen = sizeof(address);
if (bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0){   
    perror("bind failed");   
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   
}   
printf("Listener on port %d \n", serverport);

if (listen(master_socket, 3) < 0){   
    perror("listen");   
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   
}

 while(1){
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);   
    max_sd = master_socket;
    for( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++){   
        sd = client_socket[i];   
        if(sd > 0)   
            FD_SET( sd , &readfds);   
        if(sd > max_sd)   
            max_sd = sd;   
    }
    activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL ,NULL);

    if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds)){
        if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket,(struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0){   
            perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++){   
            //if position is empty  
            if( client_socket[i] == 0 ){   
                client_socket[i] = new_socket;   
                printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);
                break;   
            }   
        }


        //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands


        //printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d\n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , address.sin_port);  
        read(new_socket, buf, 1000);


 //LAST PART
 struct in_addr ip;
 ip.s_addr=clip;
 clientip=inet_ntoa(ip);//convert the integer IP to string(like 0.0.0.0)
```

When my code reach the last part so I can convert the IP into a string unexpectedly things happen, for example I have a pointer for my clientIP (char *clientIP) that is equal to 195.134.65.92 and the new client with the IP 195.134.65.95 suddenly changes my clientIP with it's value.I have tried everything but nothing help's.I used millions of printfs still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I have suspicions: try please "deep copy":
`memcpy(ip.s_addr,clip,sizeof(clip));` instead of  `ip.s_addr=clip;`
`

try intialize other fields of the struct :

```
ip.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    ip.sin_addr.s_addr = clip; 
    ip.sin_port = htons( PORT );
```

and print clip and verify if it is in host or network regrading to bytes (big or little indian)

Comment: Still nothing,also I get a warning: passing argument 2 of 'memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: and did you try to reset with memset the struct before assignment ?

Comment: No memcpy didn't fix it and also memset can't be used with struct in_addr

Answer (score 0):

Ref [inet_ntoa() documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa)

which says that "The inet_ntoa() function converts the Internet host address in, given in network byte order, to a string in IPv4 dotted-decimal notation. The ***string is returned in a statically allocated buffer, which subsequent calls will overwrite***."

So, to retain the client IP addresses, just memcopy the 'clientip' into some other buffer

Hope this helps